# too many open files when build next14

Tags: next.js

✓ Generating static pages (50/50)
[Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\Users\heade\OneDrive\Desktop\meta-itech-14\metaappclientfront\node_modules@mui\icons-material\ShareTwoTone.js'] {
errno: -4066,
code: 'EMFILE',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Users\heade\OneDrive\Desktop\meta-itech-14\metaappclientfront\node_modules\@mui\icons-material\ShareTwoTone.js'
}